# What is the maximum index of kth smallest element of max heap when stored in the form of an array?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, heap

I am new to the data structures.

I am not getting from where to start. Actually, i am not getting how to solve this?

**What is the maximum index of kth smallest element of max heap having N numbers when stored in the form of an array ?**

Any idea or aproach how to solve this will be helpful.

Comment: The kth smallest is the (N-kth) largest. You might find it easier to solve the problem by figuring out the formula for the maximum index of the kth largest.

Comment: Sry, I didn't get it. Can you please elaborate ?